# MNIST classification in tensorflow, RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I ran a Neural Network model for MNIST classification and received error-

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I checked some of the issues on stackoverflow and tried to increase the recursion limit to 1500 but did not work. 
How should I increase the limit? An how do I know what limit will cause stack overflow?

I followed the tutorial from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PwAGxqrXSCs&index=47&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfKTOs3Keq_kaG2P55YRn5v)

I have Anaconda 3.5 distribution on my windows 10 machine.

The full code is here-

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist= input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

n_nodes_hl1 = 500
n_nodes_hl2 = 500
n_nodes_hl3 =500

n_classes = 10
batch_size = 100

#height x weight
x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 784])
y = tf.placeholder('float')

def neural_network_model(data):

    hidden_1_layer= {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, n_nodes_hl1])),
                 'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))
                 }
    hidden_2_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
                  'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))
                  }
    hidden_3_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
                  'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))
                  }
    output_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3,n_classes])),
                  'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
                }

#our model= (input_data x weights) + biases

    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_1_layer['weights']), hidden_1_layer['biases'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, hidden_2_layer['weights']), hidden_2_layer['biases'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2, hidden_3_layer['weights']), hidden_3_layer['biases'])
    l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

    output = tf.matmul(l3, output_layer['weights']) + output_layer['biases']

    return output


def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = train_neural_network(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction,y))
    optimizer= tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost) #default learning rate for adamoptimizer= 0.001

    hm_epochs = 5
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            for _ in range(int(mnist.train.num_examples / batch_size)):
                epoch_x, epoch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y})
                epoch_loss += c

    print(('Epoch', epoch), ('completed out of', hm_epochs), ('loss:', epoch_loss))

    correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
    print(('Accuracy:', accuracy.eval({x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels})))

train_neural_network(x)
```

Comment: I recommend you follow the tensorflow tutorial.  Its really good:  https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/mnist/beginners/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're using code from [PythonProgramming.net's deep learning course](https://pythonprogramming.net/tensorflow-neural-network-session-machine-learning-tutorial/)

In your code, you're doing:

```
def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = train_neural_network(x)
```

You're calling the function within the function to run, which is what is never-ending.

Consider your objectives here. Should prediction be the return of train_neural_network, or the return from the neural_network_model?

```
def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. I think I might have jumped into deep nets too fast, I am back to the python lectures again for the basics now :)

Answer (score 6):

I don't know what the exact code is supposed to be, but I'm quite sure the following lines are wrong:

```
def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = train_neural_network(x)
```

This will cause an infinite recursion, and increasing the recursion limit will not solve the problem.